# Changing Android App's Name

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an android app in eclipse. I thought I named it optimuse, that is also the title of the folder eclipse created.

But when I run the app, the name appears as "MainActivity". This is also displayed on the top of the window.

How can I change this. I checked my manifest and it said:

```
 <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
...
```

I guess I need to change @string/app_name. But where can I do that?

PS: I did try to fill in a string instead of @string/app_name, but that did not change anything.

Thanks!

EDIT:

For clarity, here is my Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dh.optimuse"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

open the `Strings.xml` in `values` folder which is located in the **res** folder.

change the app_name to whatever you want

If you don't know the location.just hold `ctrl` and move the cursor to the `@string/app_name` and click. it will open strings.xml file

Comment: Thanks. Turns out the application name in strings is already "optimuse". I changed <string name="title_activity_main">Optimuse</string> to optimuse. Now the main window displays the correct name. BUT, in my application list on my phone, the app is still called "MainActivity".

Comment: Oh no... if I run the app now it says "... has stopped working" at startup. Runs fine in the emulator. Could it be a confusion with names?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answers:

What you are changing inside of `<application>` tag is the name of the app (that is shown below the app icon).

If you need to change a label for the Activity (shown at the title of the screen when the app runs), then you need to change the value of `android:label` inside of the `<actiity>` tag.